# Opencv dll issues

Tags: opencv

I was following a tutorial for object detection using opencv, I did it step by step but when I run it, I got this error -

```
The program can't start because opencv_244d.dll is missing from your computer.
Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

I don't know what is the problem because I can see this dll in opencv libraries, I have added the following to the input dependencies:

```
opencv_core244d.lib
opencv_imgproc244d.lib
opencv_highgui244d.lib
opencv_ml244d.lib
opencv_video244d.lib
opencv_features2d244d.lib
opencv_calib3d244d.lib
opencv_objdetect244d.lib
opencv_contrib244d.lib
opencv_legacy244d.lib
opencv_flann244d.lib
```

This is still not working, what can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the required dll files into the *bin* folder (that is next to *lib* folder where the *.lib* files are located), and you have two options:

1) copy the required dlls into the same folder with your application //this is a little better because it kind of prepares you for when you'll need to deploy your application on systems that don't have opencv installed (for then don't forget to build the *release* version of your application)

or
2) add to the *Path* in the *Environment Variables* your path to that *bin* folder (be carefull that the path in there are separated by ; )

Comment: Good point. PS: 3rd way is to add the dll path to `Debugging Environment`.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to [build the OpenCV libraries from source](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation) so that you can have a custom installation specific for your system (this is always better since it gives you the option of using what you want/need and also the performance is better since the libs are custom-made for your system).

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV does not contain a library file called "opencv_244d.dll".

Check all your dependencies and their names so you don't have any misspelled names. All the names are something like "opencv_name244d.dll" such as "opencv_photo244d.dll".