# Open CV with Visual Studios 2012 System Error Missing opencv_core248d.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2012, dll

Hi I am creating an application using Open_CV for the time I am having issuers getting the libraries to connect up with Visual Studios 2012

I have entered all the correct information and all the required libraries into the computer and keep getting an error message saying: 
  "The Program Can't start because Opencv_core248.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling to fix this problem."

I have tried reinstalling it 4 times now and I can also see the core248.dll library is on my PC

Any advice?

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075154/missing-opencv-core248d-dll

Comment: you have to append the folder with the dlls to the global PATH env variable

Comment: or add the dll to the same folder as your executable.